# How expensive is sending a letter by registered mail in the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, forms

I want to send some forms (say, 5 or 6 pages) by registered mail somewhere. How much should that cost me?

I'm not currently in the Netherlands to check, but a friend of mine said they asked him for 1.6 EUR for non-registered and 8.45 EUR for registered. Now, 1.6 EUR is a bit pricey, but 8.45 EUR seems like a *lot*. Could this really be the rate?

Answer (score 4):

On the Post.NL website, [it says](https://www.postnl.nl/en/mail-and-parcels/mail/registered-mail/) that

> **What does it cost?**
>
> Registered Mail is available from just 8.45 euros.

So your friend is correct. However, it also says:

> Make sure your item meets the size and weight requirements:
>
> Max. size: 38 x 26.5 x 3.2 cm 
>  
>   Min. size: 14 x 9 cm
>   Max. weight: 2 kg

and these are the dimensions of a sizable, hefty packet - much more than a letter.

So what seems to be going on is that there is no category of a registered-mail *letter* that's separate a small registered-mail *packet*. That sucks!

Comment: Realistically, the cost of a registered mail is all in the special handling (signing it off every time it is handed over from one person to another).  The size of the packet has no impact on the cost, and hence on the price.

Comment: @MartinBonner: These things are not supposed to be priced per-item. There's supposed to be tax subsidy for cheap posting of mail as a service to the population; plus, the heavier items (in many/most countries) are charged more, IIANM, than the actual cost of delivering them, offseting the cost of sending simple registered mail. In Israel, for example, a regular letter costs about 0.25 EUR or so and a registered letter is 1.3 EUR. Even if you account for differences in costs between the two states, NL is much more expensive.

Comment: "There's supposed to be tax subsidy for cheap posting of mail as a service to the population" - That's a political decision that will be different in different countries.  I can easily believe that the Netherlands might not subsidize their mail (particularly not registered mail).  Israeli letters are cheap.  A 1st class letter in the UK costs 0.75 EUR, and in Germany 0.70 EUR.  (I haven't check registered.)

Comment: @MartinBonner: If you normalize by media salary per capita, UK, Germany and Israeli are less than a factor of 2 apart, while in the Netherlands it's double. Now, it's true that a subsidy is a political decision, but Netherlands is generally a welfare state, even if the current government is conservative, which is why I was expecting a subsidy.

Comment: @einpoklum the difference between "less than a factor of two" and "double" (i.e., a factor of two) is hardly significant.  It's hardly surprising for the price of a product or service to vary by that much from one country to another.